# Difference between an if statement and an if equals statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, truthiness

Is there an actual difference between

```
if statement:
```

and

```
if statement == True:
```

Aside from the first one being shorter, does one have a higher precedence, or is one slower?

EDIT:

I realized this may not have been clear, but `statement` is usually `statement = True`.

Comment: Never write it the second way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are **not equal**. Python allows you to **define `if` statements over a large range of elements**. You can for instance write:

```
if []: # is False
    pass
if 1425: # is True
    pass
if None: # is False
    pass
```

Basically if you write `if <expr>`, Python will **evaluate the [*truthness*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of the expression**. This is predefined for numbers (`int`, `float`, `complex`, not being equal to zero), some builtin collections (`list`, `dict`, not being empty), and you can define a `__bool__` or `__len__` on an arbitrary object yourself. You can get the *truthness* of an object by calling `bool(..)` on it. For example `bool([]) == False`.

**Example where `if x` is not equal to `if x == True`**:

For instance:

```
if 0.1:
    pass # will take this branch
else:
    pass
```

will take the `if` branch, whereas:

```
if 0.1 == True:
    pass
else:
    pass # will take this branch
```

will **not take the `if` branch**. This is because a number is **equal to `True` if it is one** (`1`, `1L`, `1+0j`,...). Whereas `bool(x)` for a number is `True` if `x` is *non-zero*.

It is also possible to define an object where `==` will **raise an exception**. Like:

```
class Foo:

    def __eq__(self,other):
        raise Exception()
```

Now calling `Foo() == True` will result in:

```
>>> Foo() == True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __eq__
Exception
```

It is however **not advisable** to raise exceptions in the `__eq__` function (well I strongly advice against it anyway).

It however holds that: `if <expr>:` is equivalent to `if bool(<expr>):`.

Given the two are equal, evidently the `<expr> == True` will be slower since you do an extra call to `__eq__`, etc.

Furthermore it is usually **more idiomatic** to check if a collection is empty with:

```
some_list = []

if some_list: # check if the list is empty
    pass
```

This is also more *safe* since if it possible that `some_list` is `None` (or another kind of collection), you still check whether it holds at least one element, so changing your mind a bit will not have dramatic impact.

So if you have to write `if x == True`, there is usually something *weird* with the *truthness* of the `x` itself.

## Some background on *truthness*:

As is specified in the documentation ([**Python-2.x**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)/[**Python-3.x**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)). There is a way to resolve truthness.

In [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), it is evaluated like (**over-simplified** version, more "pseudo Python" code to explain how it works):

```
# Oversimplified (and strictly speaking wrong) to demonstrate bool(..)
# Only to show what happens "behind the curtains"
def bool(x):
    if x is False or x is None:
        return False
    if x == 0 or x == 0.0 or x == 0L or x == 0j:
        return False
    if x is () or x == [] or x == '' or x == {}:
        return False
    if hasattr(x,'__nonzero__'):
        y = x.__nonzero__()
        return y != 0 and y != False
    if hasattr(x,'__len__'):
        return x.__len__() != 0
    return True
```

and an **over-simplified** version for [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x):

```
# Oversimplified (and strictly speaking wrong) to demonstrate bool(..)
# Only to show what happens "behind the curtains"
def bool(x):
    if x is False or x is None:
        return False
    if x == 0 or x == 0.0 or x == 0j:
        return False
    if x is () or x == [] or x == '' or x == {}:
        return False
    if hasattr(x,'__bool__'):
        return x.__bool__() is True
    if hasattr(x,'__len__'):
        return x.__len__() != 0
    return True
```

Comment: So using `if statement == True` is better in that it only evaluates True/False?

Comment: No, idiomatic you write `if some_list:` to check if the `some_list` holds elements. Usually the *truthness* of an object makes sense and thus it is better to use that one.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning - when compared to numbers, `True == 1`, and `bool(x)` is `x.__nonzero__()` or `x.__bool__()` for Py2/Py3

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post. Thanks!

Comment: @TemporalWolf: That is indeed an excellent idea, I've provided some "truthness" definitions in pseudo-code Python-code.

Answer (score 2):

`if statement`: evaluates to true as long as `statement` is **truthy** (an `int` not equal to '0', `True`, a `list` with at least one element,  a `dict` with one key, value pair ..etc).

`if statement == True`: only evaluates to true if `statement` is `True`, i.e

```
>>> print(statement)
True
```

Comment: Or if `statement` is `1`, `1.0`, `1+0j`, `Fraction(1, 1)`, or anything else numerically equal to 1.